# Spring @Transactional only works if caller is also @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I am strugelling to understand why are my updates not commited when i try to use a `@Scheduled` method.
This is a simplification of my scenario:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user){
        user.setName("Doe");
    }
}
```

This service is called from two locations:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService  userService;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void getAvailableIssuers(@PathVariable("id") String id){
        User user = userRepository.findOne(id);
        userService.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```

and a service that use a `@Scheduled` method:

```
@Component
class InternalService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService  userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
    public void updateUser(){
        User user = userRepository.findOne(1L);
        userService.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I try to update the user through the `InternalService` the user never gets updated - but it is getting updated perfectly fine through the RestController. When I add the **`@Transactional`** annotation for the scheduled method (even with readOnly = true) it works.

I read the documentation from spring regarding transactions but i still don`t understand why is it not working.  I checked with the debuger and userService is in the form of a Spring Proxy.

Can someone help me with an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your operation isn't constrained to that service method: In both cases, you're retrieving the object from the repository in the calling method. Your transaction has to cover the entire collection of database operations.

As to why your controller actually *is* working, I can't say for sure with just this information, but I'd guess that you are using `OpenEntityManagerInView` and getting a transactional boundary for free.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. Spring boot uses `OpenEntityManagerInView`(spring.jpa.open-in-view property) by default and the difference comes from there.

Comment: Would it make sense to have the scheduled method annotated with `Transactional` or it would be a better idea to refactor?

Comment: @mvlupan Either could be a viable approach. It would depend on the specifics of your use case. If the "update" is really this simple, the transaction doesn't seem to be relevant at that layer in the first place, so I'd move the boundary up.